# Get machine name with highest ibps/obps from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a file containing switch names, ports, Incoming BPS, Outgoing BPS, need to find out the top talking switches

```
cat machine.csv
```

```
SWITCH, PORTS, IBPS,OBPS
ARIS, ge-0/1, 5800000000, 5800000000
CISCO, ge-0/2, 1000000000, 5700027720
JUNIPER, ge-0/3, 2000000000,3000000000
HPE, ge-0/4,3000000000,4000000000
```

in this case machine name ARIS should be returned

Appreciate if you could help, I had tried to parse from file and create a dictionary but clueless at this point how to proceed.

```
def readFile(path, machine_dict):
    with open('machine.csv', "r") as dataset:
            _, *props = dataset.readline().split(',')
            for line in dataset:
                    name, *vals = line.split(',')
                    machine_props = {}
                    for i in range(len(props)):
                            machine_props[props[i].strip('\n')] = vals[i].strip('\n')
                    machine_dict[name] = machine_props
```

Comment: sorry my bad, I was thinking more scenario's we can return based on which ever is the highest one ibps/obps

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `csv` library to read the file:

```
import csv
with open("machine.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip header
    next(reader)
    # Convert to a list of tuples
    data = list(reader)
```

Now, `data` is

```
[['ARIS', ' ge-0/1', ' 5800000000', ' 5800000000'],
 ['CISCO', ' ge-0/2', ' 1000000000', ' 5700027720'],
 ['JUNIPER', ' ge-0/3', ' 2000000000', '3000000000'],
 ['HPE', ' ge-0/4', '3000000000', '4000000000']]
```

Then, sort the data using the larger of OBPS or IBPS which are at indexes `2` and `3`.

```
highest = sorted(data, key=lambda x: max(int(x[2]), int(x[3])))[-1]
print(highest[0])
```

Output:

```
ARIS
```